# Jetpack Compose Text Hyphenation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, hyphenation, android-compose-textfield

How do I get words to break correctly to new lines in Android with Jetpack Compose? I know the functionality from the web, where I use `&shy;` for such cases.

I defined string values with possible line breaks like this: `Korrespondenz\u00ADsprache`.
Unfortunately this does not work for Android.

I use the following code

```
Text(
    text = "Korrespondenz\u00ADsprache",
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4
)
```

Currently the result looks like this:

[image]

The expected result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the default configuration of the [hyphenation configuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/Hyphens) (`Hyphens = Hyphens.None`) using:

```
   Text(
       text = "Korrespondenz\u00ADsprache",
       style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(hyphens = Hyphens.Auto)
   )
```

[image]

With [`Auto`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/style/Hyphens) the words will be automatically broken at appropriate hyphenation points.

It requires `1.3.0-rc01`

Comment: After Material Compose 1.3 was released this week, this solution works fine.

Comment: Hyphens.Auto seems to correspond to HYPHENATION_FREQUENCY_NORMAL in XML, but is there any way to hyphenate more aggressively to use up space as with HYPHENATION_FREQUENCY_FULL in XML?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `hyphen` is just recently supported in `Compose 1.3.0-rc01` release candidate as part of  `Experimental API`

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.3.0-rc01

And you might expect something like this in `TextStyle` parameters in that compose version

```
(
...
 hyphens = Hyphens.Auto
...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, compose now includes a hyphens strategy inside `TextStyle` adding `Hyphens.Auto`as the other responses explain.

Still, I was not getting the result I was looking for after adding this parameter. In most of the cases, the break '-' was not being applied since Android, by default, tried not to break the word if possible.

To allow the hyphens to be applied for example to a paragraph you also should add one more `TextStyle` property, **`lineBreak`** then it will be something like

```
 Text(
        text = "Korrespondenz\u00ADsprache",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(
                hyphens = Hyphens.Auto,
                lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph)
 )
```