# Jetpack Compose how to change Text break strategy?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How to change the way compose Text() breaks text? I want it to be broken in spaces, but not "//seed" into "//" and "seed".

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74136078/2016562

Comment: Yeh I can switch it on and off, but need to overwrite the logic...